# How to screenshot a tapped button using iOS UIAutomation?

Tags: iphone, ios, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

I tried the `tapAndHold()` function from UIAElement

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["Button"].tapAndHold()
target.captureScreenWithName("shot")
```

but this fails with a JavaScript error: `'undefined' is not a function (evaluating target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["Button"].tapAndHold()`.

**Update**:

I also tried

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["Button"].touchAndHold(1.5)
target.captureScreenWithName("shot")
```

which at least does highlight the button but when the screenshot is made it already is deactivated again. :(

Answer (score 0):

Insert delay(1).

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["Button"].touchAndHold(1.5)
target.delay(1);
target.captureScreenWithName("shot")
```

Are you running it on iPod? Also it matters on which device you are testing. I suggest using iPhone 3GS,4S to check more variety.

Comment: That doesn't work. It does all this sequentially, so the delay comes after holding it for 1.5 seconds. I run it on the simulator.

Comment: just for sake of curiosity try target.captureScreenWithName("shot") before touchAndHold